# Как суммировать данные в зависимости от значения в колонке

Tags: sql

Есть таблица `scrap` с 4-мя колонкам

```
scrap
 id:     integer
 number: integer
 type:   integer
 mass:   float
```

данные

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на выходе должно получиться новая таблица в которой будет

```
mass_t  mass_k
```

где `mass_t` сумма всех mass, а `mass_k` сумма всех `mass`, где `type=5`. В итоге должно получиться

```
mass_t  mass_k
37.55   7.25
```

В голове возникает только одна идея с `case`, но до конца не пойму как это сделать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот реализация, которая применима практически к любой СУБД:

```sql
SELECT SUM(mass) AS mass_t, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 5
                THEN mass
                ELSE 0 
                END) AS mass_k 
FROM scrap;
```

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку тип БД не был указан, держите реализацию на PostgresSQL:

```
select sum(mass) mass_t, sum(mass) filter (where type = 5) mass_k from scrap;
```